# Trying to return an Arraylist from Volley Callback

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, arraylist, android-volley

I'm pretty new to programming so I apologize if some stuff are just plain wrong, this is my first app.

I have a fragment which I'm trying to get an ArrayList from a different class that's in charge of pulling information from a JSON repository.

The idea is to pull Data from a class that's responsible for pulling data, pass it to a fragment, and inside the fragment inflate a list with the ArrayList it recieved.

this is the code inside the PullData class that is incharge of pulling information:

```
public class PullData {
   
 ArrayList<InformationField> informationList;
 RequestQueue queue;
 Context context;

    public PullData(Context context){
        this.context = context;
        queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
       informationList  = new ArrayList<>();
     
    }

    public ArrayList<InformationField> getInfo(){
        parseMain(new VolleyCallBack() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(ArrayList<InformationField> info) throws JSONException {
                informationList = info;
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(String result) throws Exception {

            }


        });
     return informationList;
    }


    public void parseMain(final VolleyCallBack callBack){



        String url = "https://data.gov.il/api/action/datastore_search?resource_id=053cea08-09bc-40ec-8f7a-156f0677aff3&filters={%22mispar_rechev%22:%22" + plateNumber + "%22}&include_total=1";
        JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                try {


                    JSONObject result = response.getJSONObject("result");
                    JSONArray jsonArray = result.getJSONArray("records");
                    String test = result.getString("total");

             
                        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                            JSONObject number = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                            model = number.getString("degem_nm");
                            String modelcd = number.getString("degem_cd");



                            carMaker = number.getString("tozeret_nm");
                            subtype = number.getString("kinuy_mishari");
                            carYear = number.getString("shnat_yitzur");
                            carGimur = number.getString("ramat_gimur");
                            ownership = number.getString("baalut");
                            date = number.getString("tokef_dt");
                           

                          


                            informationList.add(new InformationField("maker", carMaker, "maker", carModel));
                            informationList.add(new InformationField("year", carYear, "subtype", subtype));
                            informationList.add(new InformationField("ownership", ownership, "date", date));

                            callBack.onSuccess(informationList);


                        



                } catch (JSONException e) {


                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {




            }
        });

        queue.add(request);

    }
```

this is my callback interface

```
package com.OMApp.rechev;


import org.json.JSONException;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public interface VolleyCallBack {
    void onSuccess(ArrayList<InformationField> info) throws JSONException;
    void onError(String result) throws Exception;
}
```

this is the fragment where I try to use getInfo to pass an an ArrayList from PullData

```
public class MainRepo extends Fragment {


    ListView list;
    ArrayList<InformationField> informationList;


    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);


        PullData data = new PullData(getContext());
        informationList = data.getInfo();

        list = view.findViewById(R.id.tv);
        customAdapter arrayAdapter = new customAdapter(getContext(), R.layout.row, informationList);
        list.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);


    }

}
```

The problem is, when I create an PullData object inside MainRepo.java and use the getInfo() method, I get an empty ArrayList, seems like getInfo skips the onSuccess method and goes straight to the return statement, hence returning an empty ArrayList.

Comment: You've forgotten to mention what your problem is or ask a question?

Comment: @HenryTwist Apologizes if it wasn't clear, I've edited and added more info.

Comment: Please try to debug using your breakpoints and/or print statements. Check that `informationList` is properly set when you expect it to be. You can set a field watcher in IntelliJ, for example: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-breakpoints.html#field_watchpoint

Comment: Using the debugger I noticed that ```getInfo``` method runs twice, first time it just goes straight to the return ```informationList;``` statement, and second time it just runs the ```onSuccess``` method inside of it, not returning anything. Seems like the order is off, I need it to call ```onSuccess``` first, and only then return it in the ```getInfo``` method.

Comment: You've made the mistake of thinking that `onSuccess` runs as soon as you call `parseMain`. `getInfo` doesn't return the result from `onSuccess`, it sends a network request and registers a callback to run when it's finished. So `getInfo` doesn't run twice, it runs once to register the callback. Then `onSuccess` runs when the request completes. So you should be passing in a callback from your fragment as well.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this the ideal way to solve it but it works, I moved the callback function inside MainRepo, my MainRepo.java `onCreateView` looks like this now

```
 @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main_repo, container, false);
        list = view.findViewById(R.id.tv);


        PullData data = new PullData(getContext());
        data.parseMain(new VolleyCallBack() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(ArrayList<InformationField> info) throws JSONException {
                informationList =  info;

                customAdapter arrayAdapter = new customAdapter(getContext(), R.layout.row, informationList);
                list.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(String result) throws Exception {

            }
        });


        return view;
    }
```